# Windows Azure Virtual Machine and cloud service nodejs app deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine

can anyone help me with Microsoft Azure cloud service and Virtual machine connection? My nodejs app is running live on VM but not outside virtual machine. How can I deploy nodejs app to my cloud service using virtual machine? 
Note : I have added endpoints as well. Please help. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by deploy? do you have a problem accessing your application from the internet or deploying the source code?

Comment: Actually it would be good if you consider that I have made a new Virtual machine and a cloud service. Now tell me what steps should I follow to deploy my nodejs app from bitbucket which could be live and it will be hosted from VM. Thanks

Comment: I used this tutorial to make nodejs app live but it comes out to be live only on VM, not for cloud service. 
http://codetunnel.com/hosting-nodejs-applications-on-windows-server-2012-complete-with-git-deployment-and-remote-debugging-part-2/

Comment: so your problem is with kudu continuous deployment? were you able to make kudu work? why do you need a VM in the first place for a node.js project? why not use Cloud Service projects or websites instead? The cloud service layer of a VM is different than the one of a cloud service project.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. My client's demand is actually to work with VM locally hosted nodejs app. I did the port forwarding now and its working using public IP address :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did now is used port forwarding using endpoints in azure. Secondly I ran the nodejs app locally on VM, it is now accessible outside VM as well using VM's public IP address. Now I dont use cloud service anymore since there is no need. Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

When we create a virtual machine in Azure manage portal From Gallery, after selecting image and VM size, it will ask us for creating a new cloud service or selecting an exist cloud service to contain the VM.
[image]

So when you create a new one, you can put it into an exist cloud service you want.

But once the VM created, we can’t move it to other cloud service.

However, we can capture your exist VM with node.js application and environment. Then you can create a new VM using this image into the destination cloud service without redeploy environment and applications.

For more information, we can see at [Capture an image of a Windows virtual machine created with the classic deployment model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/) and [How to Capture a Linux Virtual Machine to Use as a Template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/)

Comment: Actually it would be good if you consider that I have made a new Virtual machine and a cloud service. Now tell me what steps should I follow to deploy my nodejs app from bitbucket which could be live and it will be hosted from VM. Thanks
Note : VM is Windows

Comment: And yes cloud service is attached to VM. Like we dont have to go for image such things. Thanks